# How to roll back to previous Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rollback

Recently I've just updated my Entity Framework in my project from 4.0 to 6.0, after updating I got almost 300 errors, and now it's a mess. I wish to rollback to the previous point where the Entity Framework was 4.0.

How can I do it with .Net Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Get the previous version from Source Control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to tools -> library package manager -> package manager console

then in the package manager consolo write

```
Uninstall-Package EntityFramework
```

finally when it's done

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 4.1.10311
```

you can try `4.3.1` its the newest version for 4.*

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/4.1.10331